# Why jdk works well but get mvn compile error

Tags: java, maven

My jdk works well, but I get the error when running `mvn compile`

```
PS H:\Learning\Maven> java -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

```
PS H:\Learning\Maven> mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.xxx:maven01 >---------------------------
[INFO] Building maven01 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ maven01 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ maven01 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to H:\Learning\Maven\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.566 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-23T23:18:05+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project maven01: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: What is the output of `javac -version`?

Comment: >No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?< Well *are* you? ;)

Comment: I've had problems running commands like this from PowerShell when there are path variables involved. Try running it from the CMD as admin if posible.

Comment: (assuming you're using maven-compiler-plugin defaults) You need to use `mvn --version` to the see the actual used Java Runtime. This might be different than the JDK on your PATH, hence don't trust `javac -version`.

Comment: What Robert Scholte says is very relevant. But I want to add that IF the Java version is different from what java -version returns, then the question "why?" is probably answered by looking for a JAVA_HOME environmental variable. The maven scripts use that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javac` runs fine. After I changed `jre` to `jdk` for JAVA_HOME, I didn't reopen powershell and it kept giving me errors.

Comment: You change environment variables you have to close the shell and reopen it...otherwise thy will not being updated.